# Bash conditional with grep not producing expected output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
```

projectsForArchive=/opt/tibco/run/tibbpma/log,/opt/tibco/run/tibbpmb/log,/opt/tibco/run/tibbpmd/log

archiveScriptLogsDir=/opt/tibco/scripts/LogsArchival/ArchiveLogs

backupScriptLogsDir=/opt/tibco/scripts/LogsArchival/BackupLogs

dir=$(echo $projectsForArchive | tr "," "\n")

d=$(ls /opt/tibco/run/ | grep tibbpmd)

echo $d

for i in `find $dir -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.log.*"`

do

g=${i}

if [ $(ls /opt/tibco/run/ | grep tibbpma ) = "tibbpma" ];then

```
mv "$i" "${g}_tibbpma_`hostname`_`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%s`"
```

elif [ $(ls /opt/tibco/run/ | grep tibbpmd ) = "tibbpmd" ];then

```
 mv "$i" "${g}_$d_`hostname`_`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%s`"
```

else

```
mv "$i" "${g}_`hostname`_`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%s`"
```

fi

done

for i in `find $dir -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.log.*"`

do echo $i

mv $i $archiveScriptLogsDir

done

output is coming below , which is incorrect

a.log.1.tibbpma.xxxxx

a.log.2.tibbpma.xxxxx

d.log.1.tibbpma.xxxxx

d.log.2.tibbpma.xxxxx

and correct output below

a.log.1.tibbpma.xxxxx

a.log.2.tibbpma.xxxxx

d.log.1.tibbpmd.xxxxx

d.log.2.tibbpmd.xxxxx

Please help

Comment: You could make your code a bit cleaner by using the `elif` instead of `else if`.

Comment: What is the output of `ls /opt/tibco/run/` when you run this script?

Comment: Output :b.log.1_tibbpma_c0040229.itcs.hp.com_2014-02-28-06-28-1393568931 d.log.1_tibbpma_c0040229.itcs.hp.com_2014-02-28-06-28-1393568931

Comment: But it supposed to give b.log.1_tibbpma_c0040229.itcs.hp.com_2014-02-28-06-28-1393568931 d.log.1_tibbpmd_c0040229.itcs.hp.com_2014-02-28-06-28-1393568931

Comment: @user3311501 That is what you got from `ls /opt/tibco/run/`?

Comment: No , i am getting b.log.1_tibbpma_c0040229.itcs.hp.com_2014-02-28-06-28-1393568931
d.log.1_tibbpma_c0040229.itcs.hp.com_2014-02-28-06-28-1393568931 but for second one it should be  d.log.1_tibbpmd_c0040229.itcs.hp.com_2014-02-28-06-28-1393568931

Comment: @user3311501 I did not ask what output your script given, I am asking the output of `ls /opt/tibco/run/`. Is that so hard to understand?

Comment: [tibco@c0040229 script]$ ls /opt/tibco/run/
tibbpma  tibbpmb  tibbpmd

Comment: @user3311501 OK, I got it, please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the output of `ls /opt/tibco/run/` the asker given in the comment, it always includes "tibbpma", then the condition in the first `if` statement

```
if [ $(ls /opt/tibco/run/ | grep tibbpma ) = "tibbpma" ];then
```

also will always be true. That is why the output of this script only includes "tibbpma".

Comment: +1 Good catch! OP: Please explain under what circumstances you would "expect" one file to receive the `tibbpmd` treatment when `tibbpma` exists.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons to [avoid parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and it is not required here anyway.

For the record, you would be much better off with simply `whatever | grep -q required` than running the `grep` command in backticks and comparing the output.  `grep -q` simply tells you whether the regex matches, with no output and no fancy syntax.

Also for the record, you should always double-quote your variable interpolations unless you specifically require the shell to perform word splitting on the value (which you almost never do).

Finally, take care to indent consistently.

```
source /home/tibco/script/config.cfg
dir=$(echo "$projectsForArchive" | tr "," "\n")

for i in `find $dir -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.log.*" `
do
  if [ -e /opt/tibco/run/tibbpma ];then
    dest="${g}_tibbpma_`hostname`_`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%s`"
  elif [ -e /opt/tibco/run/tibbpmd ];then
    dest="${g}_tibbpmd_`hostname`_`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%s`"
  else
    dest="${g}_`hostname`_`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%s`"
  fi
  g=${i}
  mv "$i" "$dest"
done

for i in `find $dir -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.log.*" `
do
  echo "$i"
  mv "$i" "$archiveScriptLogsDir"
done
```

I would be tempted to move the second loop inside the first loop, but I'm not sure if there are circumstances where that would not work for some reason.  Do you expect new files to appear while the script runs, or something?

Comment: my source file 

cat config.cfg

archiveScriptLogsDir=/opt/tibco/scripts/LogsArchival/ArchiveLogs
backupScriptLogsDir=/opt/tibco/scripts/LogsArchival/BackupLogs
#BW--------------------------------------------------------
projectsForArchive=/opt/tibco/run/tibbpma/log,/opt/tibco/run/tibbpmb/log,/opt/tibco/run/tibbpmd/log


[tibco@c0040229 log]$ pwd
/opt/tibco/run/tibbpmd/log
[tibco@c0040229 log]$ ls
d.log.1  d.log.2

Comment: As per script out put should be 
d.log.1.tibbpmd.*****

d.log.2.tibbpmd.*****

but out as per you script is giving

only d.log.1_tibbpma_c0040229.itcs.hp.com_2014-02-28-07-44-1393573464 

with same tibbpma problem

Comment: So explain to us where the logic in your original script is wrong?  Under what circumstances should the presence of `tibbpma` not cause files to be moved to `tibbpma`?  Or in other words, how do we know which files should go to `tibbpmd` instead even when `tibbpma` exists?

Comment: Better if you update the question with additional information, rather than drop badly formatted mumbo jumbo in comments.

Comment: problem is here beacuse 

do
  if [ $(ls /opt/tibco/run/ | grep tibbpma ) = "tibbpma" ];then
   g=${i}
   mv "$i" "${g}_tibbpma_`hostname`_`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%s`"




it has three dir tibbpma tibbpmd tibbpmb

but out put is coming with tibbpma  because it is not looking for other dir.

Comment: That's right.  Now explain to us under what precise circumstances it should look for the other dir, because we cannot know or guess how this can be resolved to your satisfaction.

Comment: Thanks for help me .I have edited the script in main section and hope , it will give you better understanding. Please help ..